# asp.net core - create an instance of a class after the app started

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, instance, publish-subscribe

I have some classes which should be instantiated after the app started. In my case, some controller can trigger an Event and I want `EventPublisher` to already have Subscribers by that moment.

```
class SomeEventHandler {
   public SomeEventHandler(EventPublisher publisher) {
      publisher.Subscribe(e => {}, SomeEventType);
   }
}

class SomeController : Controller {
   private EventPublisher _publisher;
   public SomeController(EventPublisher publisher) {
      _publisher = publisher;
   }
   [HttpGet]
   public SomeAction() {
      _publisher.Publish(SomeEventType);
   }
}
```

Is it possible to have an instance of `SomeEventHandler` by the time the `Publish` method is called?

Or maybe there are much better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without taking the `EventHandler` as a direct dependency inside the controller or the `EventPublisher`, you cannot be sure that an instance is created when you call `Publish` and that there is a handler listening to your event.

So you will need to make sure that the handler is created *somewhere*. I would personally do this in the Startup’s `Configure` method since it’s very easy to inject dependencies there, and this way, an instance will be created right when the application starts:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, EventHandler eventHandler)
{
    // you don’t actually need to do anything with the event handler here,
    // but you could also move the subscription out of the constructor and
    // into some explicit subscribe method
    //eventHandler.Subscribe();

    // …
    app.UseMvc();
    // …
}
```

Of course, this only makes sense when both the `EventHandler` and the `EventPublisher` are registered as singleton dependencies.

Comment: I got you. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use dependency injection and that will take care of getting you an instance in the controller constructor.

```
services.AddScoped<EventHandler, EventPublisher>();  or
services.AddTransient<EventHandler, EventPublisher>(); or 
services.AddSingleton<EventHandler, EventPublisher>();
```

More info about DI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: I understand it, but I'm not sure that is a good way to have an instance of this class in the controller, because it's never used there.

Comment: Yes so if you don't use it at all in the controller, remove it.

Comment: @poke, I'm using `EventPublisher` not `SomeEventHandler`. I want `SomeEventHandler` instance to be created by the time when `Publish` is called.

Comment: I'm sorry I confused you. I've edited my question with correct property of the class.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo: add it to your DI container and in it's constructor make use of EventPublisher that has also been added to the DI container